# Visual tool to generate HTML table and assign classes to individual cells

Tags: html, html-table

Does something like this exist?

The problem is, I want to have a table containing 100 or so cells, and certain cells in the table need to have a certain class (no, it doesn't really follow a pattern).

To do this manually would be **VERY** tedious. There are tools out there that let you quickly generate tables, but the problem of adding the class to the correct cells still remains. Looking at a table's source code, you don't get a good idea of where a cell lies in the table.

I came across [`Kotatsu`](http://www.askthecssguy.com/kotatsu/index.html), and it's almost perfect, apart from the fact that it only allows you to assign classes to entire rows or columns.

If there's another good way to go about doing something like this, I'd love to know!

Comment: Just remember, `<table>`'s should be used for tabular data and not layout. If you're using it for layout, use `<div>`'s instead.

Comment: I'm using it for a small web-app using a grid of tiles. No tables for layout happening here :)

Answer (score 0):

Visual editors will never beat editing the HTML source.
But if you really want, you can try [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/express/)'s.

To assign a class to a cell, just add `class='className'` to the `<td>` element

More info in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: w3schools is a good resource for tables, as their site is laid out inside of one ;) I recommend HTMLDog: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/tables/

Comment: I know how to add classes to elements. My problem is the process of having to manually write 100 cells worth of HTML, and then adding the relevant class to the correct cells in the source. You don't get a good idea of the location of a cell in the table as a whole when you are editing a table's source code.

Comment: Ok Acorn. Try Visual Studio Express if you are on windows. It have a very good html editor, and is free.

Comment: Lol shaz.. it's not the best site but it's ok. helped me a lot already.